# Does Octopus Deploy Tentacle for Linux support RHEL 6?

Tags: octopus-deploy

Does Octopus Deploy Tentacle for Linux support Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 6?  I've tried installing and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

Our [documentation](https://octopus.com/docs/infrastructure/deployment-targets/linux/tentacle) states that Tentacle for Linux is distributed as [self-contained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#self-contained-deployments-scd) .NET core application. Self-contained applications do not rely on shared-components being present on the target system, all of the necessary components for the application to run are included within the application itself.

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 (RHEL 6) required the [Runtime Identifier (RID)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/rid-catalog) rhel-x64 RID whereas linux-x64 is compatible with most distributions like CentOS, Debian, Fedora, Ubuntu and RHEL 7+. Rather than support two versions of Tentacle for Linux, the decision was made to use the linux-x64 RID.

[Here](https://octopus.com/docs/infrastructure/deployment-targets/linux#supported-distributions) is a list of Linux distributions that are supported.